# How to use Slicer content from ColumnA to filter ColumnB?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, dax

I have to build a pivot table containing information about Bug and Test grouped by team.

**Explanations**

I have all data in the same Excel sheet. In the data file there is a column for `Bug Team` and another column for `Test Team`. List content of both columns is the same but `Bug Team` can be different than `Test Team` on the same row. Please find an example in the section *Data example*.

`Bug Team` is determine by a Slicer so I used below measure to get the filter content:

```
Bug_Team_Selected =IF(ISFILTERED('Range'[Bug Team]); CONCATENATEX( ALLSELECTED('Range'[Bug Team]);'Range'[Bug Team];";");"(All)")
```

And I'm trying to build a measure `Count of test` where `Test Team` text = `Bug Team` text.

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Range'[Test Id]);FILTER(ALL('Range');'Range'[Test Team] = [Bug_Team_Selected]))
```

However, with this formula, `Count of test` measure is empty.

**Actual Result**

```
Bug Team | Count of bug | Count of test
Team1    | 2            |   
Team2    | 2            | 
Team3    | 1            | 
Team4    | 1            | 
Team5    | 0            |
```

**Data example**

```
Bug Team | Bug Id | Test Team | Test Id
Team1    | 1      | Team1     | 1000
Team1    | 2      | Team5     | 1100
Team2    | 3      |
Team2    | 4      | Team2     | 1200
         |        | Team2     | 1000
Team3    | 5      | Team3     | 1000
Team4    | 6      | Team3     | 1000
```

**Expected Result**

```
Bug Team | Count of bug | Count of test
Team1    | 2            | 1  
Team2    | 2            | 2
Team3    | 1            | 2
Team4    | 1            | 0
Team5    | 0            | 1
```

Can you please help me to understand what is not working fine?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you using Power BI?  Is there a relationship between the two sets of data?

Comment: No it is done in Excel, is it a problem ? No relationship, all is stored in the same Excel sheet.

Comment: I put it as the same question can happens on PowerBI with `DAX`

Comment: I updated tags.

Comment: Having a quick look at Excel, you can do the same modelling in Power Pivot.  Have you tried to model and relate the team data?

Comment: It is in a data model yes. Related the team data is mandatory? Because sometimes it is not the same team for a bug and for a test. I'm not sure to understand why a relation is needed in this case.